# Why are multiple-gpu slower than single gpu

Tags: tensorflow, textsum

I trained textsum at 4-gpus and 1-gpu ,I found 4-gpus is slower than single gpu , and they all have low utilization, anyone can help me resolve this problem?

Comment: that's incredibly vague; can you add more detail and context? and: do you mean "slower rate for individual operations,"? or do you mean that it literally took longer overall?

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi,I trained at 4-gpus and 1-gpu, and set max_run_steps=100000,but found that 1-gpus finished early